# How do I jade generate a list of several lines?

Tags: html, node.js, pug, preprocessor

I have the code below:

```
nav.nav-buttons
  each val in ["lock", 'monitor', "live", "folder", "video", "script", "presentation", "pack", "checked", "play-simple", "reload", "star", "lock", "tags"]
    a(href="#")!= '<svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-' + val + '"></use></svg>'
```

The compiled HTML below:

```
<nav class="nav-buttons"><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-lock"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-monitor"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-live"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-folder"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-video"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-script"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-presentation"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-pack"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-checked"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-play-simple"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-reload"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-star"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-lock"></use></svg></a><a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-tags"></use></svg></a>
```

I need the code is indented correctly, with each  be on a new line, but I have no idea how to do it.

I need the code is similar to the one below

```
<nav class="nav-buttons">
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-lock"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-monitor"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-live"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-folder"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-video"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-script"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-presentation"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-pack"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-checked"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-play-simple"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-reload"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-star"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-lock"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-tags"></use></svg></a>
</nav>
```

Comment: may I ask why you care? html doesnt care about whitespace. also i think you can find a pretty option that adds extra whitespace

Comment: I'm thinking about this question of space because I'm doing only the front-end of page, the back end will be done by someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code

```
- var desc_tags = ["lock", 'monitor', "live", "folder", "video", "script", "presentation", "pack", "checked", "play-simple", "reload", "star", "lock", "tags"].map(function(val){
-    return '<a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-' + val + '"></use></svg></a>'
- });
nav.nav-buttons!= '\n  '+desc_tags.join('\n  ')+'\n'
```

outputs

```
<nav class="nav-buttons">
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-lock"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-monitor"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-live"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-folder"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-video"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-script"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-presentation"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-pack"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-checked"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-play-simple"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-reload"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-star"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-lock"></use></svg></a>
  <a href="#"><svg class="icon-svg"><use xlink:href="svg/icons.svg#icon-tags"></use></svg></a>
</nav>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.html2jade.org/ and read http://jade-lang.com/reference/ both will help you on your quest.